# Escape & sign in batch command line parameter

Tags: batch-file

I use this batchfile test.bat:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var=%*
md "c:\testfolder\!var!"
```

This runs fine for this like "test.bat this is a test", but when special characters are used it does not work. So "test.bat test & go" creates only the folder "c:\testfolder\test ". How to escape all the special characters?

I tried using test.bat "this a & test", but when I echo !var! then it echoes with the double quotes and i don't want that.

Comment: have you tried `set "var=%*"`?

Comment: @Endoro, just tried it, does not work!

Comment: Please don't forget to escape some characters at the command line, otherwise you get a syntax error independent of the batch. Check this and put `echo "%*"` in your batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR %%d IN (%*) DO md "u:\testfolder\%%~d"
```

should work (doesn't need ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION)

It also works to make multiple directories

```
yourbatch "test & go" nospecial "oranges & lemons"
```

to create `test & go` `nospecial` and `oranges & lemons`

Now you'll have to leave town before the batch lynch mob gets you for creating silly directory names...

---

amendment for new requirement.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%d IN (%*) DO SET "var=%%~d"
SET var
ECHO =========
ECHO %var:&=^&%
ECHO ++++++++++
SET "var=%var:&=^&%"
ECHO %var%
```

Works by replacing `&` by `^&`, escaping the `&`

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works for MD but I need to do some other things with the input. I tried "FOR %%d IN (%*) DO set var=%%~d" for setting var, but still "test & so on" leaves me with "test".

Comment: How did you test that? The point is that simply `ECHO`ing the variable doesn't work because the parser will replace the variable with its value. I've amended the code to demonstrate.